# Optional function argument in OData v4 web api

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

Is it possible to define optional parameters, or pass in empty values as arguments in OData v4 functions in Web API?

Given this function definition:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder
var config = builder.EntityType<model.MyType>()
    .Collection
    .Function("Myfunction")
    .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<model.MyType>("MyType");
config.Parameter<int>("Id");
config.Parameter<string>("SomeString");
```

and this controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public System.Web.OData.PageResult<model.MyType> MyFunction(int id, string someString)
{
    return ...;
}
```

I've tried calling this function these ways:

`odata/MyType/Namespace.MyFunction(Id=123,SomeString='lalal')` Works fine
`odata/MyType/Namespace.MyFunction(Id=123)` Gives me a 404
`odata/MyType/Namespace.MyFunction(Id=123,SomeString='')` Gives me a 400 with the error 'A value is required but was not present in the request.
`odata/MyType/Namespace.MyFunction(Id=123,SomeString=null)` Succeeds, but sends the string value 'Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataNullValue' into the SomeString-paramater in the controller action. I would expect to get a regular null value instead.

Tested on versions:

- Microsoft.AspNet.OData v5.4.0

---

Upgrading to Microsoft.AspNet.OData v5.5.0-beta proved to solve the issue (partially).

---

Further digging proved that the ModelState object that wasn't valid. The modelstate object complained that there is an error in a third (?) argument with the key 'someString.String'. The error is 'A value is required but was not present in the request.'

In the code sample that Fan Ouyang provided at https://github.com/VikingsFan/SampleForOData/tree/master/ODataFunctionSample can easily reproduce that problem. Just run the sample and inspect the ModelState inherited ModelState property in the 'CustomersController'.

This seem to be a bug in asp.net web api. I changed my ModelState logic to disregard any modelstate key that contain a '.', but this is just a workaround for the underlying issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

odata/MyType/Namespace.MyFunction(Id=123,SomeString='')  or
odata/MyType/Namespace.MyFunction(Id=123,SomeString=null) should work

This is an issue and I think it has been fixed in V5.5 which will be released by the end of this month, you can try our last code and [github](https://github.com/OData/WebApi) master branch or V5.5 beta in nuget, if this issue still active, please open an issue for us, thanks!

There are lots of samples in our [github pages](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/Complex-Entity-As-Function-Parameter/)

Hope this can help :)

Comment: Tried your suggestions, but it wasn't satisfactory. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I upload my sample for you at [github](https://github.com/VikingsFan/SampleForOData/tree/master/ODataFunctionSample), you can see both SomeString='' and SomeString=null are working, and my sample version is V5.5 bate.

Comment: Upgrading to v5.5.0-beta solved parts of the problem. The modelstate contains an error. Please see my expanded question.

Comment: Add [FromODataUri] attribute for someString can solve this, you can get '' for the first request, and null for the second request.

Comment: @Andreas, Here's a [simple page](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/StringParameterIssue/) illustrating the string parameter in Web API OData. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1-Remove parameter define from source code.

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder
var config = builder.EntityType<model.MyType>()
.Collection
.Function("Myfunction")
.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<model.MyType>("MyType");
```

2-Add [FromUri] to parameter

```
[HttpGet]
public System.Web.OData.PageResult<model.MyType> MyFunction([FromUri] int id,[FromUri] string someString)
{
    return ...;
}
```

3-Now you can call method like this

```
odata/MyType/Namespace.MyFunction?Id=123
```

or
    odata/MyType/Namespace.MyFunction?Id=123&SomeString='lalal'

Comment: This will work, but note that it is a workaround. The swagger docs for this method will no longer display the parameters for this method meaning the user will need knowledge of the code to determine what to send. I think this is a limitation in the current implementation, what we would like to see is similar to optional post parameters, that the caller can omit the optional parameter altogether from the query url, that way we can add functionality to existing functions without forcing a recode of all consumers of this endpoint.